# fsspec Google Drive open parameters

Tags: google-drive-api, fsspec

How do I use fsspec to open a file on a Google Drive?  The fsspec documentation says that gdrive it is supported, but doesn't give any examples.

Simply put, I have a file at the top level of my Google Drive.  How do I open it with fsspec?

The [PyPI page for gdrivefs](https://pypi.org/project/gdrivefs/), which seems to provide the underlying implementation for fsspec, has a lot of information, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Does anybody have a simple example showing the correct options when calling open()?

-- Malcolm

Comment: This question got deleted, but feel free to get in touch on the gdrivefs repo in github

Comment: I solved my immediate problem when I found the builtin support in colab for Google drive:

from google.colab import drive

Comment: is that fsspec compatible, or something independent?

Comment: I believe the implementation in Google.colab to access Google drive is independent.  But I don't know.  The end result is that the entire drive is accessible locally as a Unix mount, with normal Unix semantics, so I guess that makes it fsspec compatible.

Comment: OK, quite different then, I think. If you are exclusively using colab, it makes sense to use their product.